# What is the origin of the phrase "caught red-handed"?

Tags: phrase-origin

I'm just wondering: why "red"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=red-handed) you will find that it is, presumably, from the blood on hands.

There are other more detailed [articles](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/caught-red-handed.html) around, quote:

> Red-handed doesn't have a mythical origin however - it is a straightforward allusion to having blood on one's hands after the execution of a murder or a poaching session. The term originates, not from Northern Ireland, but from a country not so far from there, socially and geographically, i.e. Scotland. An earlier form of 'red-handed', simply 'red hand', dates back to a usage in the Scottish Acts of Parliament of James I, 1432.
>
> Red-hand appears in print many times in Scottish legal proceedings from the 15th century onward. For example, this piece from Sir George Mackenzie's A discourse upon the laws and customs of Scotland in matters criminal, 1674:
>
> *"If he be not taken red-hand the sheriff cannot proceed against him."*

Comment: Even if you link the reference, which is good, write it in the answer as well, because if the page you link disappears or moves, this answer becomes automatically invalid. :)

Comment: Thanks, I took the liberty of fixing your blockquote and correcting a misspelling (qoute -> quote). :) You can view the edits by clicking on the "# secs/minutes ago" link.

Comment: _Out, damn'd spot! out, I say!_

Answer (score 1):

George Macdonald Fraser, in his "Steel Bonnets", a history of the feuds and raids on the English-Scots border, says that pursuing raiders across the Border was not only allowed but in some circumstances compulsory, and

> If... the robbers were overpowered, they were usually taken back as prisoners.  On occasion they were cut down in cold blood or hanged on the spot; in the language of the Border, which has passed into the language, they had been taken 'red-hand', which was 'in the deed doinge'...

If this is right (and Fraser is one of the best sources on this subject), it's from the 16th century if not before.